# Dropping unique constraint on foreign key reference of junction table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a database in PostgreSQL and want to include a many-to-many relationship between the tables. The two tables I want to include are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "meter" (
  "id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
  "nmi" integer,
  "next_scheduled_read_date" timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE "register" (
  "id" text PRIMARY KEY,
  "value" text
);
```

The many-to-many relationship I want to have is between meter id and register id. I have then created the  junction table below:

```
CREATE TABLE "meter_registers" (
    "meter_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "register_id" text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("meter_id", "register_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("meter_id") REFERENCES "meter" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ("register_id") REFERENCES "register" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I then want to create a table that references the meter_id and register_id values from the junction table above which is structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "demand_data" (
  "upload_id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
  "nmi" integer,
  "meter" integer,
  "register" text,
  "start" timestamp,
  "end" timestamp,
  "duration" Time,
  "demand" double precision
);
```

Where the meter and register reference the corresponding junction table columns. However, as the values of the junction table will not be unique I can't simply add a foreign key for the meter and register columns so I run into an error when I run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE "demand_data" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("meter") REFERENCES "meter_registers" ("meter_id");
ALTER TABLE "demand_data" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("register") REFERENCES "meter_registers" ("register_id");
```

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "meter_registers"
```

Is there a way to possibly reference the junction table columns in the demand_data table without the foreign key constraint? I know it's possible to do with a separate query once some data has been added using inner joins however, is it possible to do it through database table set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A compound foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE "demand_data" 
       ADD FOREIGN KEY ("meter","register") 
           REFERENCES "meter_registers"( "meter_id", "register_id");
```

Note: Not directly related you should avoid those dreaded double quotes.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I'll make sure to switch to single quotes next time!

Comment: No! No quotes at all. Single quotes indicate VALUES. No quotes are identifiers but Postgres converts to lower  case (thus a column name *Meter* and *meter* are the same while *"Meter"* is an identifier which must always be double quoted. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. I think the quotes actually came from the dbdocs.io export SQL function.

Answer (score 0):

If `demand_data` references `meter_registers`, it should reference its primary key. So add a single foreign key constraint on both columns.

If you want two separate foreign keys,you should probably reference `meter` and `register` directly.